# Local HTML File Form submit via Ajax to external URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am stucking a bit with my little project. 
I got an local HTML file where some Forms are in it.

All stylesheets and Javascript files are located on a webserver.

So my problem is. Im submitting all forms via AJAX. When i normally open the HTML file local on my desktop **NOTHING** happens.

When I uplod the html file on my webserver visit it, all is working fine.

So is there any solution to get the forms submitted local **while** the related JS / PHP Files are located on a webserver?

EDIT:

Information - All Stylesheets and Javascript files ( where also the ajax part is included ) are located on an runnning Webserver.

If its not working, maybe there is an other solution to get the forms submitted local by opening the html file with the browser and submitting without reloading the page?

Comment: Yes, I am working with XAMPP, so when it's not working with AJAX , maybe there is some other solution to get it submitting , without reloading the page and LOCAL. So just by opening the HTML file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you are using an apache server, you need to enabled cross-domain ajax requests in the webserver, in order to do so.

The easiest way to do so, is add this element to your apache vhosts configuration file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

I.E:

```
<VirtualHost www.test.com:80>
    ServerName www.chat.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/AMPPS/www/test"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

You also need to enabled the header module in your apache config httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```